# UITableView reload data animation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

i have a problem with UITable. When I used main UITableViewController it worked fine when I deleted row, it hide. But now I have problem because I have `UITableView`(_domainTableView) on UIViewController(MainViewController). It works fine but when I wanna delete row it doesnt hide it stay and when I shut down and shut up app this row is deleted, but i wanna automatically and with animation than before. Have you any solution?

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [backgroundGradient blueGradient];
    bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"logo"];
    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageview;

    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];

    _domainTableView.dataSource = self;
    _domainTableView.delegate = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections.count;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    Domain *domain = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    CoreDataStack *coreData = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    [[coreData managedObjectContext] deleteObject:domain];
    [coreData saveContext];
//    [self.domainTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Domain *domain = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = domain.name;

    return cell;
}

- (NSFetchRequest *)entryListFetchRequest {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Domain"];

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]];

    return fetchRequest;
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if(_fetchedResultsController != nil)
    {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self entryListFetchRequest];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                 initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

//    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.domainTableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.domainTableView endUpdates];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `fetchedResultsController` doesn't have any delegate attached. Did you try to uncomment the following line? Was it commented out on purpose?

```
//    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

Comment: When I uncomment it it show me alert `Assigning to ‘id<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>’ from incompatible type ‘MainViewController *const_strong'`

Comment: so you need to inform that `MainViewController` is implementing `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`

Comment: I know but I dont know how `_domainTableView.dataSource = self;
    _domainTableView.delegate = self;` is not enough?

Comment: No, dataSource and delegate just control tableView. Fetch result controller manages core data connection and data changes. You need to implement NSFetchedResultControllerDelegate too (which I can see is already done). You can read about this in docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `- (void)deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation` method in order to actually animate the deletion of the row. Your `commitEditingStyle` method should look something like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        Domain *domain = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        CoreDataStack *coreData = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
        [[coreData managedObjectContext] deleteObject:domain];
        [coreData saveContext];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]
    }
}
```

Some documentation which might be helpful:

[Inserting and Deleting Rows and Sections](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1)

[UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a)